# How can I get the rotation value of an object after physics simulation without keyframes?

Tags: python

```
for i in range(100):
    bpy.context.object.rotation_euler[0] = radian(random.uniform(-10.00, 10.00))
    bpy.ops.anim.change_frame(0.00, False)
    play_animation() 
    waittwosecond_or_120frame() # Python time.sleep didn't work
    pause_animation() 
    rotation = get_phone_rotation_after_animation() # line 7
    if rotation >= radian(90):
        frontflipedcount = frontflipedcount + 1
    else:
        backflipedcount = backflipedcount + 1
print(frontflipedcount)
print(backflipedcount)
```

This is the **pseudo code** of what I'm trying to do.

Actually, I'm new to Blender and Python, so I'm not sure how to implement the other codes,
but I'll only ask about the part of the code in the line 7 that gets the rotation value according to the stackexchange's rule.

I saw many answer on StackExchange for a similar case but using keyframes, but in this situation where the simulation is performed by constantly changing the initial value at random, it seems meaningless to use the final keyframe that is not linked to the initial value. there is.

Is there a way to get the final value without a keyframe, or to get the value of the keyframe that is linked to the initial value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to use `bpy.context.scene.frame_start` and `...scene.frame_end`.

````
import bpy
from bpy import context

# this is assuming you already have your physics sim baked out to keyframes.

def get_rotation_value(context):
    obj = context.object 
    scene = context.scene
    start, end = scene.frame_start, scene.frame_end 
    
    rotation = []
    scene.frame_set(start)
    rotation.append(obj.rotation_euler)
    scene.frame_set(end)
    rotation.append(obj.rotation_euler)
    return(rotation)

# returns:
# <Euler (x=0.0000, y=-0.0000, z=0.0000), order='XYZ'>
# <Euler (x=-0.6038, y=0.0485, z=-0.0178), order='XYZ'>
```
````

Comment: hmm... So can I use this after inserting a script that automatically bakes the physics simulation? thanks.

Comment: Yes, should work.